# How to pull the day of the year from a Date in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

In Groovy, there are shortcuts for finding various common variables for Date objects such as those listed below.

```
Date now = new Date()
Integer year = now.year + 1900
Integer month = now.month + 1
Integer day = now.date
Integer hour = now.hours
Integer minute = now.minutes
```

What is the shortcut for getting the day of the year?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to this question is "There isn't a shortcut" but the long answer adds "...but you can make one!"

Without any modifications you can access the day of the year from a date object with the following code:

```
Date now = new Date()
Integer dayOfYear = now[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR]
```

However if your code will be accessing that variable frequently, you can modify the `Date` class to add that property directly using the `ExpandoMetaClass` as follows:

```
Date.metaClass.getDayOfYear << { -> delegate[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR]}
Date now = new Date()
assert now[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR] == now.dayOfYear
```

More information on how to add properties with the `ExpandoMetaClass` can be found in the Groovy documentation at http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#metaprogramming_emc

Comment: You could also use calendar.instance : `Calendar.instance[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR]`

Answer (score 2):

This answer will not be relevant for now, but Java 8 is set to contain JSR-310, a much better implementation/representation of date and time.

You can see the feature in the java 8 features [list](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features#150)

In Java 8 you will have new objects for representing dates. The one most resembling Date is [LocalDateTime](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs-2012-10-25/javax/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Here is an example of how this will be done in Java (Groovy is easier of course):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
int year = now.getYear();
int month = now.getMonthValue();
int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
int hour = now.getHour();
int minute = now.getMinute();
// your answer
int dayOfYear = now.getDayOfYear();
```

This should be made available for fiddling and playing around from [Milestone 6](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones#M6) of java 8.
Milestone 6 set for 31/01/2013